# Can we sketch $\mathbf{Set}^{\mathrm{op}}$?

Tags: category-theory, set-theory

Is there a large [limit sketch](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/sketch) whose category of models is equivalent to $\mathbf{Set}^{\mathrm{op}}$?

Is there perhaps even a large limit sketch $\mathscr{S}$ generated by powers of an object $X$ such that the forgetful functor $\mathbf{Mod}(\mathscr{S}) \to \mathbf{Set}$ is equivalent to $\mathrm{Hom}(-,2) : \mathbf{Set}^{\mathrm{op}} \to \mathbf{Set}$?

(There cannot be a small limit sketch because $\mathbf{Set}^{\mathrm{op}}$ is not locally presentable.)

Comment: Well, we should use that this is complete atomic Boolean algebras, right? I guess the only question is how to sketch the "atomic" part.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes I had the same idea, but didn't add it to the question since (a) the morphisms seem to be wrong (?), (b) I also have no idea as for the atoms.

Comment: I'm not catching which morphisms you're thinking of that seem to come out wrong, morphisms that preserve the atoms? The opposite of sets should be the full subcategory of complete lattices (with morphisms preserving both meets and joins) on the objects that are atomic and Boolean.

Comment: The contravariant powerset functor is monadic. (This is a fundamental theorem in elementary topos theory.) Thus the situation is exactly as you describe.

Comment: @ZhenLin I don't get it, is there a connection between monadic functors and large sketches?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A fundamental theorem of elementary topos theory is that the contravariant powerobject functor $\Omega^{(-)} : \mathcal{E}^\textrm{op} \to \mathcal{E}$ is monadic for any elementary topos $\mathcal{E}$.
In particular, $2^{(-)} : \textbf{Set}^\textrm{op} \to \textbf{Set}$ is monadic.
It is also known that if $U : \mathcal{A} \to \textbf{Set}$ is monadic, then $\mathcal{A}$ is equivalent to the category of models of a (large infinitary) Lawvere theory $\mathcal{T}$, namely the opposite of the Kleisli category of the monad, hence also equivalent to the category of models of a (large infinitary) product sketch.

Let me be more precise about the second part.
We may assume without loss of generality that $U : \mathcal{A} \to \textbf{Set}$ is the forgetful functor from the Eilenberg–Moore category of a monad $(T, \eta, \mu)$ on $\textbf{Set}$.
Given an algebra $(A, \alpha)$, the functor $\mathcal{A} ({-}, (A, \alpha))$ defines a product-preserving functor $\mathcal{T} \to \textbf{Set}$, i.e. a model of $\mathcal{T}$, and it is easy to check that we get a fully faithful embedding $\mathcal{A} \to \textbf{Mod} (\mathcal{T})$.

On the other hand, suppose we have a product-preserving functor $M : \mathcal{T} \to \textbf{Set}$.
Let $F^{(-)} : \textbf{Set}^\textrm{op} \to \mathcal{T}$ be (the opposite of) the free algebra functor.
Then $M (F^{(-)}) : \textbf{Set}^\textrm{op} \to \textbf{Set}$ preserves products, hence is represented by some set $A$ and some $m \in M (F^A)$.
We may assume w.l.o.g. that $A = M (F^1)$.
Let $f \in T A$.
This determines a morphism $F^A \to F^1$ in $\mathcal{T}$, hence induces a map $f : M (F^A) \to M (F^1)$.
Define $\alpha : T A \to A$ by $\alpha (f) = f (m)$.
You can then verify that $(A, \alpha)$ is an algebra and that $M$ is isomorphic to the restriction of the functor represented by $(A, \alpha)$.
Thus $\mathcal{A} \to \textbf{Mod} (\mathcal{T})$ is also essentially surjective on objects, so we indeed have an equivalence of categories.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you have a reference for the second claim, that every monadic category over $\mathbf{Set}$ is the category of product-preserving presheaves on the Kleisli category? (I would like to cite this result in a paper I am working on.)

Comment: What about the converse: When $\mathcal{T}$ is a large infinitary Lawvere theory, then the forgetful functor $\mathbf{Mod}(\mathcal{T}) \to \mathbf{Set}$ is monadic, right?

Comment: It's folklore (to me). Maybe it's in one of the foundational papers from the 1960s. At any rate a closely related result appears in _Toposes, Triples and Theories_ as exercise ECMP and is attributed to Linton. Yes, if you have a large (but locally small!) infinitary Lawvere theory the forgetful functor is monadic. The Lawvere theory itself supplies the left adjoint.

Comment: Thank you!

This implies that the category $\mathbf{CABA}$ of complete atomic boolean algebras (which is equivalent to $\mathbf{Set}^{\mathrm{op}}$) is equivalent to the category of models of a large limit sketch. That sketch has an object $X$ with all powers $X^I$ and morphisms $\hom(X^I,X^J) = \hom(J,P(P(I)))$ (right?) and a rather complicated composition rule (of course coming from the monad structure of $PP$).

Do you know if there is any more easy-to-write-down limit sketch with that property? For example, I find complete boolean algebras much more easy to write down.

Comment: I never really thought about it. The fact that the free CABA on $I$ is $P (P (I))$ already confuses me. But yes, what you describe must be correct.

Comment: May I ask a follow up question here? Do you know if $\mathbf{CRing}^{op}$ can be modelled by a limit sketch? Probably it does not admit a monadic functor to $\mathbf{Set}$, right?

Comment: Any category monadic over $\textbf{Set}$ is a Barr-exact category, so that would imply every ring homomorphism can be factorised as an epimorphism followed by n effective monomorphism. I think I saw an argument showing this is false, once upon a time...

Comment: About the first comments here, there is now a detailed, self-contained and beginner-friendly proof of the equivalence between monads and infinitary Lawvere theories in the appendix of [Large limit sketches and topological space objects](https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.11115).